# How to use wexflow with .net core 2.2?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, wexflow

It seems that wexflow latest version v5.2.0 supports .net 4.6.1 and .net core 3.1

How to use wexflow with .net core 2.2?

Ref: https://wexflow.github.io/

Comment: That seems your question is answered by product owner on https://github.com/aelassas/Wexflow/issues/171